# Integral substitution paradox

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Assume $f \in L^+(\mathbb{R})$ and $x>0$.  Consider the integral

$$
\int_0^\infty  \frac{f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{y} \: dy.
$$

I am trying to make the substitution $u=x/y.$  I seem to get

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{f(u)}{u} \: du.
$$

But this doesn't depend on $x$!  Am I doing something wrong?  I know this is trivial, and I keep getting the same thing.  Is it actually true that changing $x$ doesn't affect the value of the integral?

Comment: If that's the form of your integral? Yes.

Comment: It's correct, the integral (if it exists) does not depend on $x$. Just like the ordinary integral is translation-invariant, the measure $\frac{dy}{y}$ on $(0,+\infty)$ is scaling-invariant.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed true. What you have discovered is that the "measure" $\frac{dy}{y}$ is invariant under multiplication (it is the Haar measure for the group $(0,\infty)$ with multiplication), i.e. that $\int_0^\infty f(\alpha y) \frac{dy}{y} = \int_0^\infty f(z) \frac{dz}{z}$ for all $\alpha > 0$.